# Export Form Data From Gmail - Add Column for Email Date/Time

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a webform that sends an email to gmail when the form is submitted. The email contains the form data that was submitted. I'm using a Google Apps Script to export the form data from gmail into a google sheet. The script works great, but I'm not sure how to add an additional data column for the date/time of the individual email. This would let me sort the data in the sheet by date/time of form submission. Is there a way to modify the script to add an extra column for email date/time? Here is the script:

```
    function parseEmailMessages(start) {

    start = start || 0;

    var labelName = "Temp1"; //             <-------  SET THE LABEL NAME
    var labels = GmailApp.getUserLabels();
    var threads = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    if (labels[i].getName() == labelName) {
    threads = labels[i].getThreads();
    break;
    }
    }
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {

    // Get the first email message of a threads
    var tmp,
    message = threads[i].getMessages()[0],
    subject = message.getSubject(),
    content = message.getPlainBody();

    // Get the plain text body of the email message
    // You may also use getRawContent() for parsing HTML

    // Implement Parsing rules using regular expressions
    if (content) {

    tmp = content.match(/First:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|äõüö’–_—žčâèçëıÅĂôà=ÚíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&; 
    ()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
    var first = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'BLANK';

    tmp = content.match(/Last:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|äõüö’–_—žčâèçëıÅĂôà=ÚíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&; 
    ()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
    var last = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'BLANK';
  
    tmp = content.match(/Title:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|äõüö’–_—žčâèçëıÅĂôà=ÚíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&; 
    ()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
    var title = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'BLANK';
  
    tmp = content.match(/Organization:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|äõüö’–_—žčâèçëıÅĂôà=ÚíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&; 
    ()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
    var organization = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'BLANK';
  
    tmp = content.match(/City:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|äõüö’–_—žčâèçëıÅĂôà=ÚíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&; 
    ()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
    var city = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'BLANK';
   
    tmp = content.match(/State:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|äõüö’–_—žčâèçëıÅĂôà=ÚíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&; 
    ()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
    var state = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'BLANK';
  
    tmp = content.match(/Country:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|äõüö’–_—žčâèçëıÅĂôà=ÚíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&; 
    ()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
    var country = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'BLANK';
  
    tmp = content.match(/E-mail:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|äõüö’–_—žčâèçëıÅĂôà=ÚíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&; 
    ()-,'@_.\-]+)/);
    var email = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'BLANK';

    tmp = content.match(/BLANK:\s*([\s\S]+)/);
    var blank = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1] : 'BLANK';

    sheet.appendRow([first, last, title, organization, city, state, country, email]);

    } // End if

    } // End for loop
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

You can use `message.getDate()` to get the date and time of a Gmail message; this will return a `Date` object that can be appended to the spreadsheet.

```
    // Get the first email message of a threads
    var tmp,
    message = threads[i].getMessages()[0],
    subject = message.getSubject(),
    content = message.getPlainBody(),
    timestamp = message.getDate();
```

```
    sheet.appendRow([first, last, title, organization, city, state, country, email, timestamp]);
```

**References:**

[Class GmailMessage || getDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getDate())

Comment: Thank you, Carlos.  This solution worked.  I do notice that in my spreadsheet, some of the times are a few minutes different from what I'm seeing in gmail.  But I suppose the time that is downloaded is the time that the email arrived at the gmail server, and the time I'm seeing in gmail is the time that the email was received in my actual gmail account. In any case, not a big deal.